# display ARRAY values in textfield?

Tags: mysql, ios, json

hi i am creating student details information using mysql database in Xcode want to display student information in form when i enter student name in textfield. Already i am got mysql datas in JSON array and stored in NSMutable array.now i want to fetch array values in each textfield .is it possible?
  thanks in advance.
my array values in NSLOG:

```
    (
    {
    firstName = hari;
    lastname = krishna;
    age=10;
    fathername=ragav;
    },
    {
    firstName = priya;
    lastname = amirtha;
    age=8;
    fathername=ravi;
    }
    )
```

Comment: is your each textfield for every students info in UITableViewCell in UITableView or in another place?.please let us know. it will help us.

Comment: i have  textfield in UIviewcontroller for each info.

Comment: ok means in one nib file. You are displaying all students detail Info. am i right?. please guide us

Answer (score 0):

I think its better you take only relevant student details from the DB and store that data only in the array. Dont use select * to get all data. Put a like value for the student name + primary key and get that data set.

```
UITextField *a = nil, *b = nil, *c = nil, *d = nil, *e = nil;
    NSUInteger idx = 0;

    for ( NSString *string in array )
    {
        switch ( idx++ ) {
            case 0: a.text = string; break;
            case 1: b.text = string; break;
            case 2: c.text = string; break;
            case 3: d.text = string; break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can display it in textfield. Try using this way. Follow the below steps:

1. First Initialise global array in your UIViewController. like below:

   In yourViewController.h file add the below lines of code:

   ```
   NSArray *students_Info;

   @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *students_Info;
   ```

   In yourViewController.m file add the below lines of code on first:

   ```
   @synthesize  students_Info;
   ```
2. Now add all the data from JSON response to the "students_Info" array from your NSMutableArray.
3. Now using for loop you can display all the data from array in each textfield by adding this code in you ViewDidLoad method:

   ```
   int totalInfo = [students_Info count];
   for(int count=0; count<totalInfo; count++)
   {
      // Display Students Info in each Textfield;
      NSString *studentsFirstName = (NSString *) [[students_Info valueForKey:@"firstName"]objectAtIndex:count];

      // Initialize your text field using tag value or some another way and add the text value like above everytime to your each textfield.

   }
   ```

Comment: in array count i give them my last array index values are display in button click without checking my string

Comment: Can you Please Share Some Part of Code?..it will help us